# Rails: What does this shorthand '.map(&:downcase)' mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found this code in codeschool

```
self.keywords = [title, author, description].map(&:downcase).join(' ')
```

I know the result that can convert string to downcase, but What does this shorthand `(&:downcase)` mean?

Comment: yes it seems the same, I am just confused about the usage in array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the same as:

```
self.keywords = [title, author, description].map { |keyword| keyword.downcase }.join(' ')
```

Comment: Thank, quick answer. Great help.

Comment: @CodaChang more info tha you will ever need - http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2006/04/18/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-methods/